# Ubuntu で crontab から root 権限でコマンドを実行したい

Tags: python, python3, ubuntu, django, cron

Ubuntuサーバーで、crontabにて定期的にdajangoのカスタムコマンドを実行するように、システムを組んでいます。
上記の目的を行う際の、crontabのサンプルコードが紹介されているサイト等を参考にして、自分の環境で試していますが、crontabで設定したとおりにカスタムコマンドが実行されません。

推測ですが、最初の処理の仮想環境を有効する際の、rootでの処理がうまくいっていないのではないかと考えています。
Ubuntuはデフォルトで、rootのログインがないので、crontabでコマンドを実行する際に、どのようにrootの処理をすれば良いのかわかりません。

解決策についてご教授いただきないでしょうか？

crontab内のコード

```
00  18  *  *  *  root source /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/activate && python3 /home/ubuntu/project/manage.py custom_command && deactivate
```

ディレクトリのレイアウト

```
home
__ ubuntu
____ venv
____ project
```

実行環境
Ubuntu: 19.10
Python: 3.7.5
Django: 2.2.2

---

**追記：**質問後に試した事
・crondが起動しているかどうか確認→OK

```
$ service cron status
```

・登録されているcronを表示させて確認→OK

```
$ crontab -l
```

crontab内のコードの変更（rootをはずす）→NG

```
*/1  *  *  *  *  source /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/activate && python3 /home/ubuntu/project/manage.py custom_command && deactivate
```

crontab内のコードの変更（sudo su でやってみる）→NG

```
*/1  *  *  *  *  sudo su && source /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/activate && python3 /home/ubuntu/project/manage.py custom_command && deactivate
```

$ sudo suでroot権限でコマンドの確認をすると

```
# root source /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/activate && python3 /home/ubuntu/project/manage.py custom_command && deactivate
```

下記のメッセージ

```
Command 'root' not found, did you mean:

  command 'rott' from deb rott (1.1.2+svn287-3)
  command 'proot' from deb proot (5.1.0-1.3)
  command 'toot' from deb toot (0.22.0-1)
  command 'rootv' from deb xawtv (3.106-1)

Try: apt install <deb name>
```

Comment: `sudo su -` で root になれますよ。crontab に書く前にそちらで試されては?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。追記に書いたのですが、root の変わりに、sudo suでやってみましたが、だめでした。

Comment: crontab に書く前に試すというのは、上のコメントの方法の事ではないでしょうか？

Comment: コマンドラインで `sudo su -` (末尾に `-` があります) と入力すると、root 権限に切り替わって、プロンプトも変わると思います。その状態でコマンドラインで source 〜 deactivate が動くか試してみては? ということです。動くかどうかわからないものをいきなり crontab に書くのは、動かない場合に原因を探るのが大変ですから。

Comment: rootの状態でコマンドを行いました。追記のとおりのメッセージとなります。これはrootは使えないという事でしょうか？

Comment: `root` は不要です。`source` 以降のみ実行してください。

Comment: source以降で実行すると、内容どおりに動きます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コマンドそのものは root 権限で正しく実行できるとのことですので、

```
sudo crontab -e
```

でエディタが起動するので、

```
0 18 * * * source /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/activate && python3 /home/ubuntu/project/manage.py custom_command && deactivate
```

と書いて保存し、エディタを終了すれば、18:00 に root 権限で実行されるはずです。

もしこれで動作しない場合は、代わりに

```
0 18 * * * ( source /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/activate && python3 /home/ubuntu/project/manage.py custom_command && deactivate ) > /tmp/log 2>&1
```

とすれば、`/tmp/log` にエラーが出力されるので、解決の糸口になると思います。

そうそう、タイムゾーンが合っていることも確認しておく必要があります。
コマンドラインから以下のように実行して、

```
date
```

末尾に JST と書いてあれば大丈夫です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ちなみに現在は追記に書いているように、*/1 * * * * source  というように、１分間隔で動かして試しています。0 18 * * * source /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/activate && python3 /home/ubuntu/project/manage.py custom_command && deactivateこのようにrootをなくしてもコマンドは実行されませんでした。

Comment: `crontab -e` の前に `sudo ` は付けてますよね?

Comment: はい、sudo付けて編集して、wqで終了しています。

Comment: エラーのログですが、/bin/sh: 1: source: not found　と出ています。

Comment: `source` の代わりに `.` (ピリオド一つ) にしてみてください。

Comment: source の代わりに . (ピリオド一つ) の変更でコマンドされるようになりました。

Comment: 長時間にわたりご協力いただき感謝いたします。大変ありがとうございました。