# cronに設定したshファイルが実行されません。

Tags: shellscript, cron

cron実行ユーザはrootでファイルの権限もrootです。

ファイルにはcron実行が可能なように権限付与の設定を行いました。

```
chmod u+x test.sh
chmod 777 test.sh
```

しかしcronは実行されませんでした。

cronはcrontab -eを開いて以下のように設定しています。15分おき実行が希望です。

```
*/15 * * * * /root/test.sh
```

他に見直すべきところはあるでしょうか？

Comment: cronのログは確認しましたか？

Comment: 個人的な経験ですが、一般ユーザで作成したスクリプトを`sudo crontab -e`で登録しても実行できなかったのを`crontab -e`に書きなおすと実行できたことがありました。ご質問はルートユーザなので`sudo crontab -e`でスケジュール登録するか`sudo chown payaneco:payaneco test.sh`で一般ユーザ:グループに変更することのいずれかで動作するかもしれません。※原理が分かっておらず自信がないのでコメント提案です。関連？ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62135

Comment: cron logで見る限り実行されてます

Comment: cron ジョブ自体は実行されていても、スクリプトの内容に問題があって失敗している可能性もあるので、可能な限りスクリプトの中身も質問に含めた方が回答を得られやすいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます、別のトピックで上げます。